# Get mime type in Laravel of a remote file

Tags: php, laravel

I used `file_get_contents` to get an image from a remote server. Before I do anything to it I need to check if the file is a jpeg or not.

Trying with:

```
$file = file_get_contents('http://server.com/images/new.jpg');
$mimetype = Storage::mimeType(basename($file));
echo $mimetype;
```

But all this returns is `directory`

How do I get the mimetype from a remote file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get it by calling the head request:

```
$headers=get_headers("http://server.com/images/new.jpg");
```

This would return the head data and you can get the content type from there.

`dd($headers);` and get the data you want

For example:

```
$headers=get_headers("https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/1039396/screenshots/2584581/4_1x.png");
dd($headers);
```

returns:

```
array:16 [▼
  0 => "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
  1 => "Content-Type: image/png"
  2 => "Content-Length: 59913"
  3 => "Connection: close"
  4 => "Date: Tue, 15 Mar 2016 18:04:38 GMT"
  5 => "x-amz-version-id: 7G..R3PteLad69jfLdbqN1FcyPDt2cGf"
  6 => "Expires: Thu, 12 Mar 2026 00:00:15 GMT"
  7 => "Cache-Control: max-age=315576000"
  8 => "Last-Modified: Sat, 12 Mar 2016 02:38:29 GMT"
  9 => "ETag: "f525b704270fa860869ce186fcf12de8""
  10 => "Accept-Ranges: bytes"
  11 => "Server: AmazonS3"
  12 => "Age: 32"
  13 => "X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront"
  14 => "Via: 1.1 5ec64d9502b4a51a283c9c8c16414219.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)"
  15 => "X-Amz-Cf-Id: ITHcrpnzBuzGuJsEXgI2uZ4YGx3iA_LoAAx36y4ghHDrOxo2VVRXSA=="
]
```

Comment: I did the if statement like `if(in_array('Content-Type: image/jpeg', $headers))` and it worked like a charm. Thanx!